# javascript: making api call each time vs. storing in database

Tags: javascript, sql, database, postgresql, api

I have an app that fetches all user's previous orders from a REST API when it loads up and then displays them once the data is there.  The API takes the user, iterates all the users' orders and returns a list of all completed orders.  This can take up to 3 seconds.  I am looking to speed this up.  Would it be faster to store these results in the database directly and associate it with the user?  I could update it each time a customer buys something.  Would querying database for this list then shorten the wait time when my page loads?

Comment: see here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/286788/what-is-faster-using-rest-api-or-querying-a-database-directly

Comment: There are many aspects of your issue that could cause the call to take this long.  The database could be structured poorly, the way the code is written could be iterating over objects it does not need to, etc.  People are going to yell at you to post your code by the way.

Comment: @Dom ha, I know -- it's just more of an abstract question so I didn't post code.  The API sorts through ALL orders, checks for certain criteria, then returns a list.  I was just wondering if it'd be more time efficient to fetch that list once, save it to the database, then read from the database every time after to avoid the iteration and criteria matching each time -- It'd just be a direct read

Comment: If you're concerned with browser performance loading a lot of data like that in 1 request could hurt it. I would look into pagination if that is the case for you. PostgreSQL has LIMIT and OFFSET you can add to your query https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/queries-limit.html

Comment: Taking the data from the API and replacing it into the database just seems silly.  Assuming the API is accessing a table `Orders` which has a foreign key with the users id it is likely doing a select on all orders with that user id.  You suggest making a table in a database that will have `Users` with a one-to-many relationship with `Orders`.  Ultimately doing the same thing the API is already doing for you.  What I'd look into is making your webpage feel more responsive.  Some obstacles may take a while to load but you can give the user the illusion it is fast.